# How can I force an image to be no larger than the section it's in?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a Tumblr theme and I have an avatar image that is next to the content. However the image is larger than the content and is breaking out of the section. See:

[image]

How can I prevent the image from growing beyond the section?

**HTML:**

```
<article id="" class="answer">
        <section class="question">
            <img src="http://33.media.tumblr.com/avatar_75879837bcba_128.png" alt=""><p class="asker"><a href="#">George</a> asked</p><p class="question">This is my question. I want to know what you're going to do about this. Is it a good idea?
        </section>
        <p>Answer</p>
</article>
```

**CSS:**

```
.question { padding: 0 2em; }
article { margin: 1.5em auto; }
.question img { float: left; }
.question img { width: auto; height: 100%; }
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/xb0ms51r/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing is - you need to do a clear fix, because you set the image to float, try to add the follows into your sheet sheet.

```
section.question:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
```

**Updated demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/xb0ms51r/1/

Comment: That was what was missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Add `.question img {max-width:100%; max-height:100%;}`  to your CSS in order to make sure it fits in 100% of the constraints of the section while maintaining the ration of the picture.

Simple as that!

Comment: I've tried this and it produces no change. I've looked for other classes that might conflict but can't find any.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the problem myself to show you, can you post all your code inline with your question or using [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: There are no CSS styles for the section class `question` involving height or width.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the CSS as follows for the image :

```
    .question img { 
float: left; 
width: 150px; 
height: auto;
    }
```

Set the height to auto will force the image to retain aspect ratio.

Also it may be a good idea to set html `width` and `height` in the image tag, this would be overwritten by the CSS, but structurally correct to have